# Is it possible to make a type safe Vue app without transpilation?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, flowtype, type-safety

Vue can be used without transpilation (no build step), but can it also be made type safe? That is, checked with TypeScript (or possibly Flow)?

Answer (score 2):

With Flowtype if you don't want to strip the types with a babel transpile step, the only way is to use [comment syntax](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/comments/)

Comment: Thank you, but there also needs to be Vue type definitions (declarations) that are maintained and updated parallel with Vue.

Comment: I haven't worked on Vue, but given that Vue is written with flow, they should exist somewhere, not sure how it's added to the toolchain though

Comment: Latest Vue declaration for Flow I can find are 2 years old. There are TypeScript declarations, but not sure if it's possible to get the same level of type-checking as when coding in TypeScript directly.